# Trouble uploading images to a card

Tags: trello-cards

I am having trouble uploading an image to a specific card in Trello.

Are there restrictions for uploading an image file?

Comment: There is a 10MB size restriction; is your image larger than that?

Answer (score 1):

From the [Trello Guide](https://trello.com/guide).

- There is a size limit of 10MB per attachment.
- You cannot upload attachments from the mobile site.
- There is no limit to the number of attachments on a card or board.